# Find min natural number $n$ so that $2^{2002}$ divides $2001^{n}-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Can someone explain me how this type of examples are being solved?
I know that I can watch this example like this $2001^{n}\equiv 1\ ({\rm mod}\ 2^{2002})$ but I don't know what to do when the divisor is such a large number like $2^{2002}$

$2^{2002}|2001^{n}-1$

Comment: n is the divisor of 2^2001 
Computer brute-force is a solution?

Comment: Is 0 a natural number?

Comment: @AlexSilva no it's not

Answer (score 2):

This problem is easily solved using the "lifting the exponent lemma". You can google it, but for sake of completeness I'm going to write the lemma for the special case that we will use.

First, for a prime number $p$, we denote $v_{p}(n)$ the exponent of $p$ in the factorization of $n$. So, if $v_{p}(n)=k$, then $p^{k}\mid n$, but $p^{k+1}\nmid n$.

Lemma: If $x$ and $y$ odd integers such that $4\mid x-y$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, then $$v_{2}(x^n-y^n)=v_{2}(x-y)+v_{2}(n).$$

Applying the lemma to $x=2001$ and $y=1$ gives us $v_{2}(2001^n-1)=v_{2}(2001-1)+v_{2}(n)$. Since $v_{2}(2000)=4$, we get $v_{2}(2001^n-1)=4+v_{2}(n)$. Now, because we want $2^{2002}\mid 2001^n-1$, we must have $v_{2}(n)\ge 1998$.

Therefore $2^{1998}\mid n$ and hence the minimal natural number is $n=2^{1998}$.