# Smallest n>0 such that $2001^n-1\:%$ is divisible by $\:2^{2002}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Smallest n>0 such that $2001^n-1\:%$ is divisible by $\:2^{2002}$, can you give me some hints as to what theorem/algorithm to use to approach this problem?

Comment: Well, $n=0$ is pretty small.

Comment: :( n has to be from the set of natural numbers

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021531/find-min-natural-number-n-so-that-22002-divides-2001n-1/2021720#2021720

Answer (score 2):

$2001$ is coprime with $2^{2002}$. By Euler's theorem, the smallest $n$ is a divisor of $\phi(2^{2002})=2^{2001}$.

So, one algorithm is to test for all $n=2^k$ with $k\le 2001$. This is just repeated squaring followed by reduction mod $2^{2002}$, which is not very hard to do: just repeated division by $2$.

You'll have to use arbitrary precision numbers to implement this.